# Menu Problem Drupal 7

Tags: 7, importing-exporting

I have ported a drupal 6 site to 7.

I have a client who has the ability to add links to a menu structure.

The structure is outputted using the module tb-mega-menu.

Twice since allowing the client to administer the menu there has been incidents where some of the menu items do not appear.

I was wondering if anyone knew of any bugs related to this scenario?

The solution I've already got is to just export the menu to a .txt file and import it again using the module import_menu. But this is ideally just a short term fix.

Can anyone advise me on a bug or a solution to this problem?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: it seems a cache issue? Have you try to empty the drupal cache? 
If this is the pb you should be able to create a rule to clear the menu cache after changes or new items added.

Comment: Sorry what do you mean by pb? And me and my colleague flush the cache when things are not working just to check. Any other thoughts on what it could be? Ta